# Understanding bijection $f_k:\mathbb{N}^k \to \mathbb{N}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I faced the following beautiful bijection bijection $f_2:\mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$ given by $$f_2:(i,j) \to \frac12(i^2+j^2+i+2ij+3j)$$
which allows to build bijection $f_k:\mathbb{N}^k \to \mathbb{N}$ easily by
$$f_k:(i_1, \ldots,i_k)\to f_2(i_1,f_{k-1}(i_2, \ldots,i_k))$$
By I do not understand how one could come up with idea of $f_2$. So my question

What does $f_2$ *really* mean? Is there some geometric/combinatorial construction?

Comment: It should be either [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) (see picture) or a close cousin.

Comment: Note that $$\frac{i^2+j^2+i+2ij+3j}2 = \frac{(i+j)(i+j+1)}2 + j $$ where the first term is the $(i+j)$th triangular number.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I will be happy to accept your answer, feel free to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this is

$$\frac{(i+j)(i+j+1)}{2}+j,$$

the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function). I'm answering thus under community wiki so the question can be considered answered.